# why this local parameter can change global parameter?

Tags: python, global, local

why
aaa can not be changed
but
bbb can be changed?

```
aaa = 100
def plus():
    aaa = 8   #aaa=8

plus()
print(f"aaa = {aaa}")   #aaa = 100



bbb = [100,8]
def plus2():
    bbb[0] = 5   #bbb=[5, 8]

plus2()
print(f"bbb = {bbb}")   #bbb = [5, 8]
```

Thank you.
i hope you can understand what i mean.

Answer (score 2):

`aaa = []` is *binding* to the name, which, in a function, by default, creates a local variable, regardless of whether or not a global of the same name exists (and it applies to the whole of the function; you can't read from a global, then assign to the name and create a local that replaces it from then on; if assignment occurs, even conditionally, in a function, it's a local from the moment the function is entered).

`bbb[0] = 5` is *mutating* the object bound to `bbb` without *binding* `bbb` itself; since `bbb` is never assigned/bound within the function, it remains a non-local variable (resolving to the global `bbb`).

If you want to have `aaa = []` modify the global `aaa` instead of making a new local, the function must include a `global` statement declaring it to be global:

```
def plus():
    global aaa
    aaa = 8   #aaa=8
```

If you want `bbb[0] = 5` to not modify the global, you need to copy the global (to a different name; accessing both a global and a local of the same name in a function is ugly) to a local, e.g.:

```
def plus2():
    bb = bbb[:]  # Shallow copy slice to new local
    bb[0] = 5    # Doesn't change bbb
```

Answer (score 1):

When any assignment (`variable = ...`) expression is found inside a function, the variable has its own local scope within the function. So the variable `aaa` in `plus` refers to a different object than the *global* `aaa`.

In the latter case `plus2`, you do not assign `bbb` locally so the `bbb` variable here would refer to the global `bbb`.  What you do with `bbb[0] = 5` is equivalent to `bbb.__setitem__(0, 5)`, so you change an element of `bbb` but not change `bbb` itself.

As a final note, there is a `nonlocal` or `global` keyword to change the behavior (but they should be used in special cases only with a proper discern and only when it's reasonable to use them).

```py
aaa = 100
def plus():
    global aaa
    aaa = 8

plus()
print(f"aaa = {aaa}")   # aaa = 8
```

Comment: Read more: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names